# Destructuring first Array item or How to force Mongoose to return Object instead of 1-item Array

Tags: javascript, mongoose, ecmascript-6

Mongoose's `.find` method returns Array even if one result is found, its logical

But for example i know for sure that result is 1-item or empty Array

How can i destructure result or beg mongoose to do that?

```
Payments
  .find({ ... })
  .sort({ ... })
  .limit(1)
  .then(result => {
    result = result[0]; // need to write more conditions, this may throw an exception when array is empty
  })
```

Comment: `.then(([result]) => …)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case isn't specific to Mongoose.

It can be:

```
.then(results => {
  if (results.length) {
    const [result] = results;
    ...
  }
});
```

Or:

```
.then(([result]) => {
  if (result) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Both ways are valid in Mongoose, because a result is expected to be truthy if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findOne` method instead of limiting your query results:

```
Payments
  .findOne({ ... })
  .sort({ ... })
  .then(result => {
    // ...
  })
```

Comment: Oh, I thought it is not possible to mix `.findOne` and `.sort` because Robo 3T (MongoDB client) doesn't allow this. Thanks.